# when changing hibernate index location (lucene) at runtime index is not getting stored on new location

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I have requirement in my application where we need to store index on the bases of user so I am trying to change location at runtime, but index is not getting stored on new location and if I am giving same location in config file then it is getting stored

I am using following code to change location

```
LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean

localSessionFactoryBean.getConfiguration() .setProperty("hibernate.search.default.indexBase", "New_loc") 
localSessionFactoryBean.getObject().getCurrentSession() //on this session object i am doing DAO opertation .
```

Rest configuration I have given in config file. I have invested my 3 days to find the solution for this but no success. Any help would be really appreciated.
My code to get session is following

```
protected Session getSession() {

        Configuration conf=sessionFactory.getConfiguration();


        conf.setProperty("hibernate.search.default.indexBase","c:\\testdata" /*CustomerContextHolder.getFile()!=null?CustomerContextHolder.getFile():defaultFileLocation*/);

        ContextHolder.getOrBuildSearchFactory(conf);
        return sessionFactory.getObject().getCurrentSession();
        //  sessionFactory.getObject().openSession();
    }
```

and Bean is following

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">${hibernate.jdbc.batch_size}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>  <!-- Options are [validate, create, update, create-drop] -->
         <!-- <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop> -->

        <!-- Connection pool size -->
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">${hibernate.connection.pool_size}</prop>

    issue -->
        <prop key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">org.hibernate.search.store.impl.FSDirectoryProvider</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.search.default.locking_strategy">single</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">c:\abc</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.search.lucene_version">LUCENE_35</prop>
    </props>

</property>
```

Update Code :

```
Session getSession() {

        Configuration conf=sessionFactory.getConfiguration();

                conf.setProperty("hibernate.search.default.indexBase","c:\\testdata");
        //conf.configure(); Need to commented otherwise shwoing duplicate Property

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry= new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                conf.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        return   (Session) conf.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry).openSession();

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `getOrBuildSearchFactory` of `ContextHolder`? e.g `ContextHolder.getOrBuildSearchFactory(config)`

Comment: after changing hibernate properties using `setProperty` you have to build sessionFactory again.

Comment: Thanks for comment so do i need to call(getOrBuildSearchFactory) this before localSessionFactoryBean.getObject().getCurrentSession()  and after localSessionFactoryBean.getConfiguration() .setProperty("hibernate.search.default.indexBase", "New_loc").Will it make transaction issue becuasue i have tried  
with disconnecting curent session and then tried to opennew seesion using openSession then it give transection related errror

Comment: can you show updated code?

Comment: any update on answer?

Comment: Hi really sorry for late reply!! I am not able to find ContextHolder in hibernate 4.1.0.Final version .Do we have something else in hibernate 4.1.0.Final

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this : (For Hibernate 4.x)

```
Configuration cfg = localSessionFactoryBean.getConfiguration();
cfg .setProperty("hibernate.search.default.indexBase", "New_loc");
cfg.configure();
serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            cfg.getProperties()).build();
sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

Comment: There is one more issue which i found Some time my previous code works while some time it doesn't write data to index

Comment: @user1047873, code according to Hibernate 4.x is updated. This works for me

Comment: @Amough :Really Thanks for your kind help .I will check this in evening will update you soon

Comment: Hi I have tried as you mentioned but still not success  i have shared my code as well

Comment: I am using hibenate 4.1.0.Final

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this dynamic changing of index base will work. Also rebuilding the factory seems dodgy. Did you have a look at index sharding - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#advanced-features-dynamic-sharding. This should allow you to split data according to let's say a user id.

If sharding does not solve your problem, you maybe could refine your actual usecase. Maybe there is another solution.

Comment: Thanks Let me check this as i am not aware about this

Comment: I am not able to update hibernate version on 4.3.0.Final and for shading i need to use this

Comment: @user1047873 shading? what do you mean?

Comment: sorry my mistake it is dynamic sharding.

Answer (score 0):

After lot's of effor finally i figured out the reason for this.If i will close the sesson after each database write then only index file will get stored on new location .However this is not efficeint approach but this is how it works